# javascript Function not working when var is passed as parameter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension

i was trying to create a js function inside a chrome extension that is supposed to have a string as a parameter and replace every letter of that string to a specific char and it is working if you pass the parameter as : 'con("string is here");' , but if pass as a var that contains the string it doesn't work like : `con(varThatHasString);`  and chrome console error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at con` ,

my js:

```
var letters = [
    'q','ض',
    'w','ص',
    'e','ث',
    'r','ق',
    't','ف',
    'y','غ',
    'u','ع',
    'i','ه',
    'o','خ',
    'p','ح',
    'a','ش',
    's','س',
    'd','ي',
    'f','ب',
    'g','ل',
    'h','ا',
    'j','ت',
    'k','ن',
    'l','م',
    'z','ئ',
    'x','ء',
    'c','ؤ',
    'v','ر',
    'b','لا',
    'n','ى',
    'm','ة',
    '[','ج',
    ']','د',
    ';','ك',
    ',','و',
    '.','ز',
    '/','ظ',
    "'",'ط',
    ' ',' ',
    '1','1',
    '2','2',
    '3','3',
    '4','4',
    '5','5',
    '6','6',
    '7','7',
    '8','8',
    '9','9',
    '0','0'
     ];//all the used charchters
var lastSelect;// last selected text from page 

function con(english) {//convert from english to arabic

    var aoutput = new Array;
    var chars = english.split(''); 
    for(var i=0;i < chars.length;i++){
    aoutput.push(letters[letters.indexOf(chars[i])+1]);
 }
    var ar = aoutput.join();
    var res = ar.replace(/,/g,'');
    document.getElementById('copy_box').value = res; 
    return res;

}
//code will run only when there is text already selected on page
chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {code:"window.getSelection().toString();"}, function(results){ 
lastSelect = results[0];
});
con(last_select);
```

when i run the extension it just doesn't show anything in the text field ,however when i go to the console and try the function itself it works great
and try to `con(last_select);` it works great and it shows output in text field

Comment: The code in your question never calls `con`. Post the calling code for more specific help.

Comment: Sorry i didn't show the right code i fixed it now

Comment: Extension API is asynchronous so you need to use the result **inside** the callback or promisify the API and switch to async/await syntax as shown in the proposed duplicate topic. BTW there's a typo in your code: `last_select` should be `lastSelect`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no reason that a `string` variable can't be passed into your `con()` function. If you were passing in *anything* other than `undefined` (even `null`), it would throw a `TypeError`. Therefore, the variable you're passing *must* be incorrectly `undefined`.

Ensure that whatever variable you pass into there is **not** undefined and your function will work just fine.

Edit:

Now that you've included your code, @wOxxOm's comment is the real answer; the problem is that `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is async so you're calling `con(last_select)` before `last_select` is set.

Comment: that is actullay what i am trying to know , why my `lastSelect` is always returned as undefined

Comment: Now that you've included your complete code, @wOxxOm's comment is a valid answer.